# Instaloader library throws 'date_utc' error when given a link to download a post

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, instaloader

Here is my code:

```
import instaloader

def download_instagram_post(post_url):
    # Create an instance of Instaloader
    loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

    # Download the post
    try:
        loader.download_post(post_url, target='#posts')
        print("Post downloaded successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

post_url = input("URL: ")
download_instagram_post(post_url)
```

When I give it a link to download it returns `Error: 'date_utc'`. why is this problem caused and how can I fix it and download the post from the given link?

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add this line in your code and everything will work correctly:
post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(loader.context, url.split("/")[-2])

```
import instaloader

def download_instagram_post(url):
    try:
        loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

        # Load the post from the URL
        post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(loader.context, url.split("/")[-2])

        # Download the post to the current directory
        loader.download_post(post, target='#downloads')

        print("Post downloaded successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while downloading post: {str(e)}")

post_url = input('URL: ')
download_instagram_post(post_url)
```

Let's break down the line `post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(loader.context, url.split("/")[-2])` and explain its purpose:

1. `instaloader.Post.from_shortcode()`: It is used to create an instance of the `instaloader.Post` class by providing the context and the shortcode of the Instagram post. The `from_shortcode()` method retrieves the post details using the shortcode.
2. `loader.context`: `loader` Is responsible for handling the Instagram session and loading the post. `loader.context` refers to the context of the loader instance, which contains the necessary information and settings for the Instagram session.
3. `url.split("/")[-2]`: This part of the code splits the given URL using the forward slash (`/`) as the delimiter and selects the second-to-last element from the resulting list. In the case of an Instagram URL like "https://www.instagram.com/p/Ctt5XupruCM/", the shortcode is present as the second-to-last element after splitting the URL.

So, by combining these elements, `instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(loader.context, url.split("/")[-2])` creates a `Post` instance for the specified Instagram post by extracting the shortcode from the given URL and utilizing the loader's context to retrieve the post details.

I hope this clarifies the purpose of that line in the code. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: This looks like an AI-generated answer. This is a friendly reminder that this is, for now, against Stack Exchange guidelines.

Comment: Perhaps A.I helped me formulate the answer, but the error I found myself. I've now edited the answer to look less A.I generated!